# unable to create a table using of# MySQL

Tags: java, hibernate, struts-config

hibernate is not able to create a table why...?

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/e_shop</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

AnnotationConfiguration cfs=new AnnotationConfiguration();
        cfs.configure("daoHibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml");
        new SchemaExport(cfs).create(true,true);
```

my all table are getting alter and table getting drop then again created why how to start a new session please give a reply

Answer (score 4):

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

because of this, each time it will drop and create tables.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

use `update` instead of `create`.

Comment: Thanks for the response